# Type-dependent constant in template function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, template-specialization

I want a static array in a templated function whose length depends on the type with which the function is specialized. My first attempt was:

Header:

```
template<typename T>
struct Length {
    const static size_t len;
};

template<typename T>
void func(){
  static T vars[Length<T>::len]; // len not const. according to compiler!
  // ...
}
```

Source file:

```
template<> const size_t Length<double>::len = 2;
template<> const size_t Length<float>::len = 1;
// ...
```

However, `g++` does not compile this and complains

> error: storage size of ‘vars’ isn’t constant

So, what exactly is the problem here? I know that the size of a fixed-length array needs to be a constant and known on compile time, but that seems to be the case here.
When I write

```
const size_t len = 2;

void func(){
    static double vars[len];
}
```

it compiles without problems.

**Question:**

What is wrong with the code and which alternatives are there for achieving the desired behavior? I would not like to allocate the memory during runtime...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `const` variable to be considered a compile-time constant (formally, a *constant expression*), its value must be available at point of use. Which means the specialised definitions would have to go to the header file.

If done as just specialisations of the member, as you did, I believe that would give you a multiple-definition error. You should be fine with specialising the entire class template, and keeping the static member definition inline:

```
template<typename T>
struct Length;

template <>
struct Length<double>
{
  static const size_t len = 2;
};
```

---

As a side note, your program was originally invalid: an explicit specialisation must be declared before use. Which means you'd have to at least *declare* the specialisation of `len` in the header (or everywhere you intended to use it).

Comment: The pattern of specializing the class template is called a metafunction. Definitely the right solution here.

Comment: An explicit specialization of a member doesn't need to be previously declared. It will match the member declaration of its containing class template.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I don't think that's a metafunction. As per [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/metafunction.html), "A *metafunction* is a class or a class template that represents a function invocable at compile-time."

Comment: @Potatoswatter C++11 14.7.3/6: "If a template, a member template or a **member of a class template** is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation
to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required." (emph mine)

Comment: (first thread): Yes, that's exactly what we have here: a function mapping types to values.

Comment: (second thread): Oh, I misunderstood at first but now I see what you mean there. By the way, you can forward-declare an explicit specialization simply by omitting the initializer: `template<> const size_t Length<double>::len;` followed by `template<> const size_t Length<double>::len = 2;`. This is C++98 [temp.expl.spec] §14.7.3/15, in C++14 ¶13.

Comment: @Potatoswatter 1. I misunderstood you a bit. Yes, the entire template `Length` is a metafunction; I thought you meant just the specialisation. 2. Yes, as I said, it must be at least declared, in the way you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles fine for me with `g++ 4.6.3` and produces the output

```
2
1
```

`array.cpp`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Length {
    const static size_t len;
};

template<typename T>
void func(){
  static T vars[Length<T>::len]; 
  std::cout << (sizeof(vars) / sizeof(*vars)) << std::endl;
}

template<> const size_t Length<double>::len = 2;
template<> const size_t Length<float>::len = 1;

int main(){
  func<double>();
  func<float>();
}
```

```sh
$ make array
g++     array.cpp   -o array
$ ./array 
2
1
```